# How to yield key and value in a dictionary if conditional is met

Tags: python, generator, generator-expression

Here is my current code

```
guests = {'Jane': 35, 'Kyle': 20, 'Justin': 43, 'Ayla': 22}

age_check = (key, value for key, value in guests.items() if value >= 21)
for guest in age_check:
  print(guest)
```

I am curious how I would get the output of every key and value where the value is over than or equal to 21 using a generator expression.

I have tried the code that is shown above which returns a SyntaxError.
I have also tried returning both the key and value but only iterating through the values which also returned a SyntaxError.
I have also tried a few miniscule changes but am currently stumped.
I am assuming both the value and the key have to be mentioned after the `if` but am unsure how or where.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `age_check = ((key, value) for key, value in guests.items() if value >= 21)`

Comment: Post the traceback message so that we can more clearly see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Displays for lists, sets and dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries): *The comprehension consists of a single expression followed by at least one for clause*. In your case, the expression `key, value` is ambiguous in this context (is that a tuple being generated or is the second value in the tuple a generator) so must be encased in parentheses.

```
age_check = ((key, value) for key, value in guests.items() if value >= 21)
```